# Any suggestions to build an indoor map application?

Tags: javascript, maps

I need to build an indoor interactive map with Javascript, like google maps but an indoor one(like a house map, or a building map),interactive like this: http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html (This example is made with a country map, i need a map of a house or a building, an indoor map!)

There are softwares like leaflet, that can build interactive maps, but not indoor maps.

My problem is that i need suggestions about softwares or tools to be able to build indoor maps!.

i'm so lost right now, can you help me where to start? I need a lot of help!!

Comment: [You already asked this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936762/any-suggestions-for-an-interactive-indoor-map-applicationin-js) do not post the same question multiple times. If a question you post gets closed, fix the question to address the issue it was closed for.

Comment: Did you find a solution, I am working on one now too?